# Angular dimamic elementRef name (don't know how it named)

Tags: angular

i have a lot of code like below:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Some label</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="pickerPay">
    <input matStartDate [(ngModel)]="service.filters.startFrom" placeholder="from" (focus)="pickerPay.open()">
    <input matEndDate [(ngModel)]="service.filters.startTo" placeholder="to" (focus)="pickerPay.open()">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerPay"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #pickerPay></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

second row from bottom with **#pickerPay**

can i somehow make this code with **"id"** (elementRef or how it named) from variable

that will help me

Answer (score 0):

The mat-date-range need a template reference variable that was a ,mat-date-range-picker (in your case `#pickerPay`). You  need **not** id(*)

Inside a `*ngFor` you has no problem to use the same "template reference variable" else you should has as many differents template variable as mat-date-range

(*) BTW you always can use `[id]="variable"` but if you're using in Angular id you probably are using Angular incorrectly

**Update** to create a *ngFor, you need create an array of object. There're many solutions, e.g. imagine you has an array filterData. In one query can be, e.g.

```
filterData=[
  {label:"Create",startField:"startFrom",endField:"startTo"},
  {label:"Update",startField:"updateFrom",endField:"uptateTo"},
  {label:"Delete",startField:"deleteFrom",endField:"deleteTo"}
]
```

You can use some like

```html
    <!-- a *ngFor over filterData-->
    <mat-form-field *ngFor="let data of filterData">
    
      <!--see the use of data.label-->
      <mat-label>{{data.label}}</mat-label>
    
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="pickerPay">
        <--see the [(ngModel)]-->
        <input matStartDate [(ngModel)]="service.filters[data.startField]" placeholder="from" (focus)="pickerPay.open()">
        <input matEndDate [(ngModel)]="service.filters[data.endField]" placeholder="to" (focus)="pickerPay.open()">
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerPay"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #pickerPay></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Remember, if we are repating code, we can re-think the problem using an array of object

Well, another option can be change the properties of your filter and use an array or similar, really I don't know much more about your problem

Comment: i have menu "date ranges" for filter list data by dates periods (created/updated/deleted/date_next_action and other) in some lists i have more then 4 date ranges and was thinking how i can make some component where i just use ngFor by dateRangeFilterName

Comment: if i user same element reference name angular scream about using same name

Comment: @НикитаСереда,  really I don't know much about your problem, I updated the answer with one idea, perhafs this help you to improve it